# Problem debuging "list index out of range" error in Deck Class

Tags: python

I have a class here that makes a deck of cards. It has methods to deal a card and reset the deck to the original (in order and intact) state.

I get an error for line 23 `out_card = self.cards[0]`) when the program's grader runs it: `IndexError: list index out of range`

It says it is running an error when it tries to "deal" more than 52 cards. But when I try to run more than 52, it just returns a None type, like it's supposed to.

Not shown in code: the Card class. This is just a class I wrote whose `__repr__` class turns `Card(4, "C")` to `Card("4 of Clubs")` for example.

```
import random

class Deck:
    def __init__(self, shuffled = False):
        cards = []
        for suit in ["C", "D", "H",  "S"]:     
            for rank in range(2,15):   
                cards.append(Card(rank, suit))
        self.cards = cards
        self.shuffled = shuffled
        self.dealt_cards = 0
        if self.shuffled == True:
            random.shuffle(self.cards)
        
    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        pass
                       
    def deal_card(self):
        if self.dealt_cards <= 51:
            out_card = self.cards[0]
            if self.dealt_cards <= 50:
                self.cards.pop(0)
            self.dealt_cards += 1
            return(out_card)
        else:
            return(None)
         
    def __repr__(self):
        return("deck(dealt " + str(self.dealt_cards) + ", shuffled=" + str(self.shuffled) + ")")
        
    def reset(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in ["C", "D", "H",  "S"]:     
            for rank in range(2,15):   
                cards.append(Card(rank, suit))
        self.shuffled = False
        self.dealt_cards = 0
```

Where could it go out of range? I couldn't find the problem. Python 3 for anyone wondering

I can't say exactly what raised the error, because it comes from the program I am taking's auto-grader. I can't say for sure, but I would think the code is something along the lines of:

```
for i in range(55):
    print(my_deck.deal_card())
```

Comment: What code do you run with this class?

Comment: If you are talking about what lines of code were called to raise the error, check the new edit at the bottom of the post.

Comment: That code does not run into an error. Maybe because you called `reset()` before, which has `cards.append()` instead of `self.cards.append()`.

Comment: THAT WAS IT. thank you Paul. I just needed to call self.cards.append() instead.

Comment: I'm glad you got your solution. Please accept the answer so that we close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you always use `self` when refering to class attributes from within the class methods.

Change the following in `reset()`:

```
cards.append(Card(rank, suit))
```

To:

```
self.cards.append(Card(rank, suit))
```